# Horizontally rotate (flip) a button

Tags: ios, swift

I've made a quiz app that gives the user a choice of four multiple choice buttons.  I'm trying to have the buttons flip back to front in order to show a new set of answers for each question but I am making zero progress.  I'm finding the docs and the error messages extremely challenging.

I'm including this code only because I know I need to include something; I'm fully aware that it's garbage.

```
func rotateButton(newname:String) {
    let buttonImage = UIImage(named: "yellow_button.png")
    for button in choiceButtons! {
        var new = UIButton()
        new.setImage(UIImage(named: "yellow_button.png"))
        new.setTitle(newname)
        button.addSubview(new)
        UIView.transitionFromView(button, toView: new, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there's no such thing as `setImage` or `setTitle` for a UIButton, so your code will never compile. You have to call `setImage:forState:` and `setTitle:forState:`.

Second, don't make an extra button at all! There's no need, and you'll just confuse the heck out of yourself when you lose track of your buttons entirely. Just change the values of each existing button and flip it:

```
UIView.transitionWithView(button, duration: 1,
    options: .TransitionFlipFromLeft | .AllowAnimatedContent,
    animations: {
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "yellow_button.png"), forState:.Normal)
        button.setTitle(newname, forState:.Normal)
    }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for matt answer.

Swift 5:

```
UIView.transition(with: button, duration: 1,
    options: [.transitionFlipFromLeft, .allowAnimatedContent],
    animations: {
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "yellow_button.png"), for: .normal)
        button.setTitle(newname, for: .normal)
    }, completion: nil)
```